# jQuery works on fiddle cant make it work on the website

Tags: jquery

is there a specific place to load the js file int the correct order? is it being overridden?
http://amf.wp.land/wp-content/themes/transfers/jsautoload/dropdown.js

https://jsfiddle.net/megapt/8nn3houc/

```
document.getElementById("pickup1").selectedIndex = 23; //Option 10 
$('#pickup1').on('change', function(){
   console.log($('#pickup1').val());
    $('#dropoff1').html('');
    if($('#pickup1').val()==441){
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="469">Albufeira</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="471">Alcantarilha / (Aqualand)</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="475">Alfamar (Aquamarina)</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="478">Algeciras (Spain)</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="480">Aljezur</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="482">Almancil</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="619">Altura</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="621">Armação de Pêra</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="622">Ayamonte</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="624">Balaia</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="625">Beja</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="626">Boliqueime</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="627">Bordeira</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<<option value="628">Burgau</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="637">Cabanas de Tavira</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="636">Cadiz</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="635">Cartaia</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="634">Carvoeiro</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="633">El Portil / El Rompido</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="632">Estoi</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="631">Évora</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="441">Faro (Airport)</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="629">Guia</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="648">Huelva</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="646">Isla Antilla</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="645">Isla Canela</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="644">Lagoa</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="643">Lagos</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="642">Lisboa</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="641">Loulé</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="640">Málaga</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="639">Moncarapacho</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="647">Monchique</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="661">Monte Gordo</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="660">Montechoro</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="659">Olhão</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="658">Olhos de Água</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="657">Oura</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="656">Penina</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="655">Porches</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="442">Portimão</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="654">Praia da Galé</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="653">Praia da Rocha</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="652">Quarteira</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="651">Querença</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="650">Quinta do Lago</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="649">Sagres</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="662">São Brás de Alportel</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="663">Sevilha</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="664">Silves</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="665">Sta. Bárbara de Nexe</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="666">Tavira</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="667">Vale do Lobo / Vale Garrão</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="668">Vila Real de Sto António</option>');
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="669">Vilamoura</option>');
    }else{
        $('#dropoff1').append('<option value="441">Faro (Airport)</option>');
    }
});
```

its working on the fiddle...

Comment: check console in your website maybe there is error

Comment: managed to make it work loading this script on the footer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle loads the jQuery library first, then the library you provided, and the javascript in the script window at last. In your website, you should also load jQuery first, preferably in `<head>`, followed by `dropdown.js`. The custom script code should be placed in a `<script>` tag at the end of the page, where all DOM elements are loaded.